# ES error:Request processing failed; [172.17.1.128:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]];

Tags: java, elasticsearch

the console show:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[hivHRf8sRnKAn6pyUnFVZQ][quickreply][0]: RemoteTransportException[[hivHRf8][172.17.1.128:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]];
```

es version :

```
{
"name" : "b9a94c35e8b1",
"cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
"cluster_uuid" : "jMIbEzZTRh2IltEDBQYGQQ",
"version" : {
"number" : "7.2.0",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "docker",
"build_hash" : "508c38a",
"build_date" : "2019-06-20T15:54:18.811730Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
},
 "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When i search and sort ,then the console show this.

the search code:

```
map.put("quickReplyList",quickReplyRes.findByOrgiAndCreater(super.getOrgi(request)  ,MainContext.QuickType.PUB.toString(), null , PageRequest.of(super.getP(request), super.getPs(request),Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "sort"))));
```

I think the "sort" does not exit in the ES,so i want know how to add the sort property

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: I think the "sort" does not exit in the ES,so i want know how to add the sort property

Comment: It's definitely not the full query. Also can you share the error message that you can find in the ES server logs, it might contain more information?

Comment: No mapping found for [sort] in order to sort on

Comment: Instead of specifying `sort` you need to use the field name on which you'd like to sort